# Technical meaning and use of getClass and getResource

Tags: java

I m new in programming. I watch online tutorials of Java and I came with this `getClass().getResource()` what is the technical use of these terms.Can anyone help me.

Comment: Have you read the Java API spec on them?

Comment: See the javadoc of `Object` for `.getClass()`, and the javadoc of `Class` for `.getResource()`

Comment: These aren't things I'd typically expect to see in an introductory course on Java; where did you see these come up?  Have you started with a decent Java textbook?

Comment: Always try to read documentation first and then ask if you still have a question.

Comment: No i have started learning java via online video tutorials of "thenewboston".

Comment: can anyone please suggest me about a good java tutorial for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load some resource not using absolute/relate path of your file system, you should use the classloader. Your resource (for example icon.ico) can be packaged in `foo.jar` but some other icon with the same name can be also in `bar.jar`. The `getClass().getResource()` statement helps to specify where the classloader will look for.

Answer (score 0):

getClass().getResource() will give you an URL to a file inside your jar. This is useful if your program depends of i.e an datafile and you want to make sure it is always available. getClass().getResourceAsStream() is the same concept only it returns a stream.

Answer (score 0):

getClass() is defined in the Object class to return the "runtime class of this Object".
where as  getResource() "finds a resource with a given name". for example if you pass
getClass().getresource("sample.png") returned URL will be a File:// url for a sibling file with the name "sample.png".
In short it gives the absolute path of the file in your directory.